# using statement assigning a package to a variable.

Tags: c#, using

What does it mean when you have something like this:

`using var p = <package name>`

on top of the source code?  Is `p` a global var?  If so, isn't that bad?  What good does it do compare to

`(using var p= <package name>) {  }`

Thanks

Comment: P is alias its not a global variable.

Comment: I have no idea what a "package" is. If you're working with C#, please don't use java terminology. java is a dinosaur language from the 90's, while C# is modern technology. See [MSDN: using Statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/yh598w02.aspx). Other than that, post real code because the one you posted is not valid C#.